# Wordpress and Demandware

Tags: php, wordpress, demandware

Is there a way to keep an existing WordPress site and ‘attach’ to a content slot / asset in Demandware?

We are having a new ecommerce platform implemented and I want to use keep the WordPress blog as the CMS is used by a number of contributors that don't have an understating of HTML and the inbuilt navigation takes little or no maintenance.

I'm also unsure if I can create the styled landing page within Demandware...

Comment: just put the shop on a subdomian (eg shop.mydomain.com) and point that to the hosted service

Comment: That was the only solution i could think of too.  However, i wanted the Demandware site to have all the 'content' from the blog available within its on site search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be if you can export your Wordpress content somehow (ideally in Demandware's standard XML format) and import it into the shop. Once it becomes content assets you can do with it what you like.

You can of course also crawl Wordpress or use some RSS feed and then convert the blog content if exporting a defined XML is not an option. Transformation could be done at the Demandware side.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to SGD's answer, Moku Collective has developed a WordPress plugin that pushes content to Demandware as content assets. It does not automatically place that content within a slot. However it does solve half of your problem and allows you to publish to any instance as needed. This publish workflow allows for single posts or all published posts to be pushed to Demandware.

*Update:* We have open-sourced the plugin: https://bitbucket.org/mokucollective/demandware-wordpress-ocapi-plugin

If you have questions, contact us via our website: [mokucollective.com](http://www.mokucollective.com)

Answer (score 1):

My vote would be use the Moku plug-in, or DIY a solution to export the content from WP to DW content assets.  This would allow you to better control the content via schedules, customer groups, etc.  Another solution is to call the Wordpress API via server-side call from a Demandware script (using httpClient) to pull the content in real-time from WP....and ideally add some caching layers to the call to keep server performance high.

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer may come a bit late, but there is a Demandware, currently Salesforce Commerce Cloud, LINK certified product that can help you with exactly what you were looking for. Its called BlogLINK and it brings wordpress blog articles to Demandware as Content Assets. You can use WP as a CMS and only run schedule jobs in BM to bring articles to DW, very easily. Your blogsection becomes a subfolder of your DW store, which is much better for indexing than a subdomain, as it makes search engines index blog and ecommerce traffic all together. 
You can find the product on DW LINK here:http://www.demandware.com/link-marketplace/bloglink